# Transaction Propagation in JDBI

Tags: java, transactions, jdbi

I am using JDBI at the data layer, it doesn't use spring.
In the project, I am calling a method which is marked with  `@Transaction` from a method which itself is annotated with `@Transaction`.

```
@Transaction
public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
   employeeDao.update(employee);
   departmentDao.updateDepartment(employee.getDepartment())
} 

@Transaction
public void updateDepartment(Department department) {
  ...
}
```

I know how Spring's `@transaction` propagation works, but how does it work in the case of JDBI? what is the default propagation level? How to change it if needed?

As suggested in the docs https://jdbi.org/#_transactions we can manage transactions programmatically. But would like to know behavior in the annotation-based configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JDBI, there is no concept of `REQUIRED_NEW`. Both the calls would run in a same transaction,

The below text is from the JDBI mailing group:

> There's no concept of parking a transaction and starting a separate inner transaction automatically at this time, although of course, it's straightforward enough to do so manually with two Handles.

https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/jdbi/CAHjY6CVkSN%2BJ_KpEG_T1NXf%2B%2BwwOK7GxXz72ofs%2Bf_wONmL_Rw%40mail.gmail.com.